# Can a power cut damage the software?

Tags: power, memory

When unplugging the power source of a device that is writing some data "A" to an SD card, also other data "B" might get corrupted. (This is detailed [here](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/questions/50345/is-it-okay-to-just-pull-the-plug/50347#50347).)

Regarding Arduino projects *without* an SD card, is it OK to remove the power source of Arduino microcontrollers anytime because the memory inside them uses a different technology than SD cards do (what are the names or differences of the respective technologies)?

Or are there several entirely independent memories - one for data and one for software/sketches?

Or do Arduino projects have to be programmed such that there are periods without data-writing and an LED indicates when it is safe to cut off the power?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First we need to look at the different memory technologies in a microcontroller:

- First you have the flash memory. This is where the program is saved, but it can also be used to hold user data. On AVR based Arduinos it can only be written while programming or by the bootloader. But boards like the various ESPs can also have a little file system in it. Here you can get problems with a power loss while write operations happen.
- The RAM holds the current value of all variables. But it also always looses all data when unpowered. This is normal behavior because it is volatile memory. A power loss won't change anything here.
- That leaves us with EEPROM, a non-volatile memory type. You can corrupt your data with a power loss during write operations.

Then we need to look at the data structures. Most memory in Arduinos and similar boards a organized as a simple array of bytes. EEPROM is usually handled this way. If you write a data structure and have a power loss during that time, you must view this data structure as corrupt (for example writing a string with 20 characters, but while writing the 6th byte the power goes out). Other data is not harmed. On the other hand when you use a filesystem in flash like SPIFFS a write action in a file also involves handling a filesystem table. Outage during handling of the table might corrupt your filesystem integrity, thus can also harm other files.

SD cards are a special case, since their internal controllers move the data around to some unknown algorithm to implement wear leveling. This is not done with standard microcontrollers (you would need to implement it yourself if needed). The actual memory technology is also just flash, but you don't want to disturb the SD card while its handling its wear level algorithmus. That might corrupt the SD card completely. Also the linked answer talks about the SD card of a Raspberry Pi, which has a complete OS running on it. Running an OS involves way more changing non-volatile data than a microcontroller typically needs. So its way less likely to have the same situations with a microcontroller.

> Or do Arduino projects have to be programmed such that there are periods without data-writing and an LED indicates when it is safe to cut off the power?

Normally that is not needed, though it depends on your application and how the sketch handles the data. Are you saving data to non-volatile memory? How often do you do it? How often do you cut the power? If you are writing to byteswise memory like EEPROM, can you tolerate specific data corruptions? How much data are you writing each time?

Without assessing all these questions you cannot really say. Typically beginners just start without precaution in that direction. When you see problems after replugging, then you still can add an activity LED to the project.

Comment: TL;DR If the sketch doesn't write to non-volatile memory, it is safe to pull the plug at any moment.

Comment: Thanks! Regarding "Outage during handling of the [filesystem] table": I guess "handling" means writing. So if I want to regularly write some data A1, A2, A3 and avoid damaging existing data "B", is it good to allocate one big empty file "A" and regularly write data into it (kind of a "filesystem within a filesystem"), instead of regularly creating several small files?